# ReactGoogleMapsAPI не работает маркер

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api

Мучаюсь с меткой в Гугл Мапс. Когда добавляю код маркера

```
<Marker
position={center}
onLoad={onLoad}
onClick = {handleClick}
/>
```

, сохраняю, все работает. При перезагрузке страницы - пропадает. Полный код прикреплен ниже

[КОД](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-frog-jcc3mm?file=/src/Map.jsx:171-176)

Comment: ходить по посторонним ссылкам не очень удобно. По правилам сайта рекомендуется приводить минимально вовспроизводимый пример, если он нужен.

Comment: UPD: понизил реакт до 17.0.0 - работает

Comment: @atmose Добавьте ваш React код по [интсрукции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx), пожалуйста